# What do we think of "soft / meta" questions?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I've been asking questions about programming language design at a higher level than the more technical kinds of questions I suppose many people are expecting to see here.

For example, so far, I've asked:

- [What design strategies matter for new languages seeking long-term, widespread adoption when approaching a problem-domain with existing languages?](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/q/656/251)
- [What can be learned from problems (and associated solutions / goals to strive for) C++ committee members have identified with their proposal culture?](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/q/736/251)
- [How can isolated focus on syntax be counterproductive in the earlier stages of a language's design?](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/q/888/251)
- https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/q/939/251 (admittedly, I don't think this one is particularly good, and after thinking about it more, have decided to self-delete it)
- [How does the C++ Committee generally decide what does or doesn't go in its standard library?](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/q/983/251) (I plan to follow up on this with a deeper "why" question)

I've got even more planned and not yet drafted- along the lines of:

- A series of Q&A about what the creators of specific well-known, well-established, and fairly mature languages regret about the design of their own languages, why, and what they would do differently given the chance. [here's the first one](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/q/1114/251).

I've got some that I wouldn't call quite as high-level, but still a little bit higher-level than the majority of the questions that are commonly posted right now:

- [What techniques have existing languages used or considered using to enable their evolution? Why were they chosen/considered? How have they fared?](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/q/924/251)
- [Is the mental overhead / cognitive load of learning and remembering how a language's features work measurable? If so, how?](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/q/923/251)

Compared to the majority of the other questions that are being asked, in general, these are a step or a few steps higher-level.

**Looking at both the questions (and their answers), what do we think of these?** Do we want more or less of these types of questions? Does the quality of the questions and answers have any impact on whether we want questions like this?

In addition to those, here are some questions I invite you to ask and discuss:

- What do you think the internet can gain if we let these questions be on-topic here? Are these types of questions important / valuable questions in the field of programming language design and implementation?
- What might we suffer if we decide to let these kinds of questions be on-topic?
- Is there anything about these types of questions that make them fundamentally unsuitable for Stack Exchange as a whole?

Comment: I have my own answer to these questions, but (uncharacteristically?), I'm going to not instant-self-answer, and will wait a bit to listen first.

Comment: Personally I like those sort of questions. I hope this meta does to but I fear they all qualify for the "too broad"/"list question" hammer.